# Can't `:uploadArchives` become a bit faster?

Tags: java, maven, gradle

`:uploadArchives` task is taking impossibly long time (about 14 minutes) to upload a single module.

I found out that it's the bottleneck of I/O (using `iotop` command), but I believe it can't be faster because I'm using SSD now.

Are everyone waiting for this impossibly long archiving work? Aren't there any techniques to faster this?

Comment: Are you running with `--daemon`? It speeds gradle up a little bit.

Comment: Where are you uploading the archives _to_? How big are they? How fast is your **upstream** connection to that location?

Comment: From my own experience I can tell that uploading archives is not a performance problem. I takes a few seconds. When any network task is taking so long, I would search for a network problem. Maybe something like a collision in local network address (two machines with the same ip) ?